# How to turn IBus input method on after installing ibus-m17n for Bengali-avro?

Tags: ibus, internationalization

I have installed `ibus-m17n` from Software Center. Selected and added Bengali-avro in Input method under IBus Preferences. IBus was added to the Startup Applications in power cog menu. In the Language Support, keyboard input method is set to IBus. It is seen from the top Panel of IBus-Bengali-avro and the Input Method is off. No change after pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Spacebar</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Use "Prabhat" keyboard, which is better supported in Ubuntu, easy to type and no installation needed. Go to System Settings > Keyboard layout > Add (Click + sign) Bengali(India or Bangladesh)